# how to see changed lines of code between 2 branches for specific file type?

Tags: git

I want to create a metric that shows me "changed lines of code" per "Bug" between two  Versions (in my case branches in git).

Because our application has a lot of .swf files, I don't need to count those swf's files and I just want to count the java, xml and so on.

Is there some kind of tool who does that? or a git command like `git diff --stat` for a specific file type?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Does

```
 git diff --stat branch1..branch2 -- '*.java' '*.xml'
```

do the job for you?

For me it does, but with `*.c` and `*.h`.

Comment: Its working great is there a way to write the output into a file.

Comment: If you are in a Linux terminal, you can do `git diff ... >output.txt`.